# Set up local environment to step into API code

Tags: api, debugging

Currently I have a PHP application running on my local machine, but unable to step into local API code.  Instead API calls are directed to the production API.

How can I set up my local PHP application to step into API code in Visual Studio Code?  Currently both PHP and API codes are in the same workspace in VS Code.

Here's what in the .env file:

```
 API_URL=https://api.mydomain.com
```

I believe I need to set up a local URL for the API but not sure where to start.

-Thanks!

Comment: If the API is running on an external server, you need to setup remote debugging

Comment: Thanks Nico for your reply.  What I want to do is to have both PHP and Node.js API code running and debugging them locally in VS Code.  This would save me much time deploying API code updates.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it